# Фильтрация QuerySet по датам

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, filter, django-filter

Я пытаюсь отфильтровать `QuerySet` таким образом, чтобы `date.today()` находилась внутри диапазона, между значениями полей БД `start_date` и `end_date`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

**models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id_group = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    name_group = models.CharField(max_length=256,)
   
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True,)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_group

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Group'
        verbose_name = 'Группа работ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Группы работ'
```

Я добавил это условие при выгрузки в отчет, но полагаю есть более правильный вариант решения задачи:

```
    if group.start_date <= date.today() <= group.end_date:
        ws.append(data)
```

Comment: `lte`, `gte` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

```
today = date.today()
ws = Group.objects.filter(start_date__lte=today, end_date__gte=today)
```